# Cordova: Day change event

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am developing a cordova based mobile application.
In that, I need to reset a count stored in localstorage, when day changes.
Right now If I close the app and start it another day, I check the current day with previous day and reset the count if new day is detected.

The problem is that if the app is opened today and is in memory when starting it next day, the count will be the same as previous day.

How can I detect the day change event in cordova/javascript?

Comment: Down Voter, Please let me know why so I can improve.

Answer (score 1):

Add a setInterval in your app.

Lets say set interval is 1 hour, then call that date change check condition!

Eg:

setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);

Hope it helps!